# How to convert this woocommerce json format to list in C#?

Tags: c#, entity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfDTy.png)    [
        {
            "id": 2532,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "number": "2532",
            "order_key": "wc_order_FgqugoSiTCm8C",
            "created_via": "checkout",
            "version": "3.8.1",
            "status": "completed",
            "currency": "SGD",
            "date_created": "2020-05-22T07:03:19",
            "date_created_gmt": "2020-05-22T07:03:19",
            "date_modified": "2020-05-22T07:06:40",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2020-05-22T07:06:40",
            "discount_total": "0.00",
            "discount_tax": "0.00",
            "shipping_total": "42.00",
            "shipping_tax": "0.00",
            "cart_tax": "0.00",
            "total": "47.50",
            "total_tax": "0.00",
            "prices_include_tax": false,
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_ip_address": "157.46.19.210",
            "customer_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
            "customer_note": "",
            "billing": {
                "first_name": "Sala",
                "last_name": "Printer Test",
                "company": "",
                "address_1": "sdfgsdf",
                "address_2": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "postcode": "476456",
                "country": "SG",
                "email": "ecommerce@unipro.com.sg",
                "phone": "5674645"
            },
            "shipping": {
                "first_name": "Sala",
                "last_name": "Printer Test",
                "company": "",
                "address_1": "sdfgsdf",
                "address_2": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "postcode": "476456",
                "country": "SG"
            },
            "payment_method": "cod",
            "payment_method_title": "Cash on delivery",
            "transaction_id": "",
            "date_paid": "2020-05-22T07:06:40",
            "date_paid_gmt": "2020-05-22T07:06:40",
            "date_completed": "2020-05-22T07:06:40",
            "date_completed_gmt": "2020-05-22T07:06:40",
            "cart_hash": "4ebf26dee924ed591c6160c0f21d7fe4",
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 42356,
                    "key": "is_vat_exempt",
                    "value": "no"
                }
            ],
            "line_items": [
                {
                    "id": 17,
                    "name": "COCONUT OIL KERAL",
                    "product_id": 2511,
                    "variation_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "tax_class": "",
                    "subtotal": "4.50",
                    "subtotal_tax": "0.00",
                    "total": "4.50",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "taxes": [],
                    "meta_data": [],
                    "sku": "106096",
                    "price": 4.5
                },
                {
                    "id": 18,
                    "name": "STAR",
                    "product_id": 2512,
                    "variation_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "tax_class": "",
                    "subtotal": "1.00",
                    "subtotal_tax": "0.00",
                    "total": "1.00",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "taxes": [],
                    "meta_data": [],
                    "sku": "106081",
                    "price": 1
                }
            ],
            "tax_lines": [],
            "shipping_lines": [
                {
                    "id": 19,
                    "method_title": "Flat rate",
                    "method_id": "flat_rate",
                    "instance_id": "20",
                    "total": "42.00",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "taxes": [],
                    "meta_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 155,
                            "key": "Items",
                            "value": "COCONUT OIL KERAL × 1, STAR × 1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "fee_lines": [],
            "coupon_lines": [],
            "refunds": [],
            "currency_symbol": "$",
            "_links": {
                "self": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://uniprogroups.com/collegecollection/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/2532"
                    }
                ],
                "collection": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://uniprogroups.com/collegecollection/wp-json/wc/v2/orders"
                    }
                ],
                "customer": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://uniprogroups.com/collegecollection/wp-json/wc/v2/customers/1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2527,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "number": "2527",
            "order_key": "wc_order_ru3ymWKbxuaib",
            "created_via": "checkout",
            "version": "3.8.1",
            "status": "processing",
            "currency": "SGD",
            "date_created": "2020-05-22T04:32:25",
            "date_created_gmt": "2020-05-22T04:32:25",
            "date_modified": "2020-05-22T04:32:25",
            "date_modified_gmt": "2020-05-22T04:32:25",
            "discount_total": "0.00",
            "discount_tax": "0.00",
            "shipping_total": "42.00",
            "shipping_tax": "0.00",
            "cart_tax": "0.00",
            "total": "44.50",
            "total_tax": "0.00",
            "prices_include_tax": false,
            "customer_id": 1,
            "customer_ip_address": "157.46.19.210",
            "customer_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36",
            "customer_note": "",
            "billing": {
                "first_name": "Sala",
                "last_name": "Printer Test",
                "company": "",
                "address_1": "sdfgsdf",
                "address_2": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "postcode": "476456",
                "country": "SG",
                "email": "ecommerce@unipro.com.sg",
                "phone": "5674645"
            },
            "shipping": {
                "first_name": "Sala",
                "last_name": "Printer Test",
                "company": "",
                "address_1": "sdfgsdf",
                "address_2": "",
                "city": "",
                "state": "",
                "postcode": "476456",
                "country": "SG"
            },
            "payment_method": "cod",
            "payment_method_title": "Cash on delivery",
            "transaction_id": "",
            "date_paid": null,
            "date_paid_gmt": null,
            "date_completed": null,
            "date_completed_gmt": null,
            "cart_hash": "932d91bdbf989a4c8c3ea868474dfed8",
            "meta_data": [
                {
                    "id": 42316,
                    "key": "is_vat_exempt",
                    "value": "no"
                }
            ],
            "line_items": [
                {
                    "id": 14,
                    "name": "AMBI 1100",
                    "product_id": 2514,
                    "variation_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "tax_class": "",
                    "subtotal": "0.00",
                    "subtotal_tax": "0.00",
                    "total": "0.00",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "taxes": [],
                    "meta_data": [],
                    "sku": "106015",
                    "price": 0
                },
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "name": "GRB GASOGOLLA",
                    "product_id": 2515,
                    "variation_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "tax_class": "",
                    "subtotal": "2.50",
                    "subtotal_tax": "0.00",
                    "total": "2.50",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "taxes": [],
                    "meta_data": [],
                    "sku": "106014",
                    "price": 2.5
                }
            ],
            "tax_lines": [],
            "shipping_lines": [
                {
                    "id": 16,
                    "method_title": "Flat rate",
                    "method_id": "flat_rate",
                    "instance_id": "20",
                    "total": "42.00",
                    "total_tax": "0.00",
                    "taxes": [],
                    "meta_data": [
                        {
                            "id": 131,
                            "key": "Items",
                            "value": "AMBI 1100 × 1, GRB GASOGOLLA × 1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "fee_lines": [],
            "coupon_lines": [],
            "refunds": [],
            "currency_symbol": "$",
            "_links": {
                "self": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://uniprogroups.com/collegecollection/wp-json/wc/v2/orders/2527"
                    }
                ],
                "collection": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://uniprogroups.com/collegecollection/wp-json/wc/v2/orders"
                    }
                ],
                "customer": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://uniprogroups.com/collegecollection/wp-json/wc/v2/customers/1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried this ,but came err

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '_Model.orderClass+oderlist' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Comment: if you would add your code, we could give you more concrete feedback, but the error message is quite clear: You're trying to deserialize a list of objects to a single object. Modify your deserialize call, it should look similar to this example `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);`.

Comment: yup! thanks it's working

Answer (score 0):

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type '_Model.orderClass+oderlist' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. **To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface** (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array.

You're trying to deserialize a list of objects to a single object. Modify your deserialize call, it should look similar to this example

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
```